# How to calculate frictional losses in convergent nozzles and convergent-divergent nozzles?

Tags: aerodynamics, engine

I have searched up a lot of articles and papers relating the subject but not satisfied with the results. Most of them are showing the losses in pipes which I already know from Darcy-Wiesbach equations and Moody diagram and all but I do not know how the formulas/equations will change when the cross section area will vary. Please help to calculate frictional losses for rocket nozzles. All mention if any other loss are associated.

Comment: Fluid dynamics is a very, very complex subject, and not one that will be solved in the comment section of a forum. Surface friction will be the same (direction of travel and velocity) however pressure changes will have a greater effecct. Bernoulli's equation is a good start